# Copula identification

Tags: r, independence, copula, bivariate

I am looking a bivariate data and am trying to find a correct copula. I have been looking at the well known bivariate copulas (the archmedian copulas) but as I was looking, none of them seem to be the correct fit to the dependence structure. The dependence structure is shown here[image: a]

Comment: Your data doesn’t follow any known copula. Try mix-copula

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am still a novice in terms of copula identification. Is there an R package and article to read up on mixed copulas? or possibly a package that can help identify the mixture of copulas?

Comment: Mixture copula is a combination of several copulas. There are some articles about mixture copula but there are advanced. Search about mixture D-vine copula, for example.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide more details. What is the purpose of the exercise, i.e. what is your ultimate(!) goal. How is the data generated? What do you know about your copula? Is it really only this scatter or anything else? Do you need a parametric copula or can you live with empirical distributions? And so on ...

Comment: @Maryam Your statement "doesn’t follow any known copula" is very strong. How are you able to conclude this from looking only at a (crowded) scatter plot?

Comment: @gg Thank you for your comment. I know all known copula family shapes. This does not follow anyone of them. If you know a copula with this shape, could you please share it with me as am very interested in copula.

Comment: @gg as you know we can use scatter plot to identify copula. Even though the data is large, it is still does not follow a well known copula family.